# Questions about Checkbox Inputs in the Summary section of a Details tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a site that populates a list of tasks using the detail element, with the name in the summary element and the instructions following. I would also like to add the ability for Admins to bulk-select tasks for approval, but i'm having a small cosmetic issue with the checkbox I added. I would like it so that the checkbox populated within the summary element with each task does not cause the detail window to expand when clicked.

Right now the basic code looks like:

```
<detail>
   <summary>Task Name<input type='checkbox'></summary>
   Task Instructions
</detail>
```

When the checkbox is selected, it activates the whole detail element causing the instructions to expand. Is there a way to prevent this without also causing the  element to stop functioning entirely?

The entire site is using JS/JQuery, CSS, and HTML mostly, so I have a few options available to me.

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Attach a click event listener to the checkboxes and stopPropagation on the event so it doesn't bubble up to the summary element

Answer (score 0):

```
<details id="mydetails">
    <summary>Click here<input type="checkbox"></summary>
    <p>content</p>
</details>
```

This should NOT expand your entire details element if you just check the checkbox.
Checkout the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ybcarLx7/1/

Comment: I adjusted the formatting of your post, to post a code block you can either: highlight the code and press ctrl+k to automatically indent as code or, manually, place an empty line before and after the code, and indent each line an additional four spaces.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Thanks for that David and Barmar. Points noted!

Comment: Even in the jsfiddle, i'm having the same issue. Could it potentially be a problem with the version of browser used in this office?

Comment: @Enigmatic - What browser are you using and what version?